# Cannot change the frame of UILabel in marquee

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I am using [this](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/10/simple-scrolling-uilabel-for-iphone.html) code for UILabel marquee. But i am not able to change the height of the label. I am using label font size as 60. Label text go out of bounds from its base side. Even after debugging for long time i am not able to find out the reason why me text is getting cut at the bottom.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The above link has the two files attached. The code is vey big. I am using the same class given in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `[string sizeWithFont:]`. Code below works fine for me.

```
NSString* message=@"Polska pozdrawia";
CGSize fontSize=[message sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:60.0f]];
AutoScrollLabel* label=[[AutoScrollLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, fontSize.height)];
[label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:60.0f]];
[label setText:message];
[self.view addSubview:label];
[label scroll];
```

Comment: Thanks. But if the text is very small which can fit in the view and can be seen as whole then i don't want it to scroll.How can i do that.

Comment: you can experiment with `fontSize.width` to check if you want to scroll or not and then call or not call `[label scroll`] method